# UiPath Timeout reached while screen locked

Tags: user-interface, uipath, uipath-robot, uipath-activity

I have developed one UiPath **attended Bot which runs well when screen is unlocked but failed when it locked**, i tried with both simulate and default input types for click and type into, but my problem is how long screen is not locked everything is running smooth, but once screen is locked, getting below errors “**Timeout reached**.”,“level”:“Error”,“logType”:“Default”, and “Could not find the UI element corresponding to this selector”

Any Suggestion is much appriciated, Thank You

Comment: Well that sounds intended. Otherwhise you need to install UiPath as a service on your PC, that should also work. Btw what is your task doing?

Answer (score 0):

We also faced same issue on UNO RPA c# tool.
we are trying to openurl throughb rpa bot we have openurl activity. that working fine for chrome browser but when we are using IEWITHEDGE driver that time Bot which runs well when screen is unlocked but failed when it locked. This is for UNO RPA c# tool.